# Update htaccess in several WP sites at once

Tags: htaccess

I make changes to htaccess file quite often and having several sites to manage, I have to update every htaccess file in every site.

I was wondering how to automate this task...

I was thinking about SSH to communicate between my computer and remote servers.
But I don't know which scripting language would be the best.

Thanks for any advice!

Regards,
Roberto

Comment: Are all these `.htaccess` files identical? What sort of changes are you making? Are you wanting to automate the editing as well, or just the transfer to the live site?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for your reply.
In fact I forgot to specify what sort of changes...
`.htaccess` files are *not* identical so I have to edit them as well!

Comment: So, what exactly are you wanting to automate? And what significance does the "scripting language" have here? Are you using version control/Git?

Comment: @MrWhite
I insert often new snippets into .htaccess file (mainly for security purposes). I would like to replicate these same snippets into several .htacess files in remote servers.
Scripting language means what kind of script should I use to achieve this.
I've never used version control/Git system. It could be a solution for this task?